# Create variable based on two other variables

Tags: python, if-statement, apply

## Initial question

In Python, I would like to create a new variable `c` based on the value of `a` and `b`.

```
if a in ('GBP', 'AUD', 'CNY', 'NZD'):
    if b == '[00Y, 01Y]':
        c= '90'
    elif b == '[01Y, 02Y]':
        c = '85'
    elif b == '[02Y, 03Y]':
        c = '80'
    elif b == '[03Y, 04Y]':
        c = '75'
    elif b == '[04Y, 05Y]':
        c = '70'
elif a in ('EUR', 'USD', 'CHF', 'CAD', 'SGD', 'HKD', 'JPY'):
    if b == '[00Y, 01Y]':
        c = '95'
    elif b == '[01Y, 02Y]':
        c = '90'
    elif b == '[02Y, 03Y]':
        c = '85'
    elif b == '[03Y, 04Y]':
        c = '80'
    elif b == '[04Y, 05Y]':
        c = '75'
    elif b == '[05Y, 07Y]':
        c = '60'
    elif b == '[07Y, 10Y]':
        c = '55'
```

`a` and `b` are columns of a dataframe and I have to use `apply` to finally obtain what I desire.

Although this perfectly works, I think it is long code for such a small operation and I wonder if there is a more elegant way to do the same. I know the `np.select` condition but it forces me to repeat the condition on `a, which I find is not elegant either.

Thanks,

## Reformulation of the question

My initial question is maybe not clear enough.
I want to compact the following code without having to repeat all conditions:

```
def f1(a, b, c, d):
    if a == 1 and b <= 5 and c in ('abc', 'def') and d:         s = 75
    if a == 1 and b <= 5 and c in ('abc', 'def') and not d:     s = 83
    if a == 1 and b <= 5 and c == 'xyz' and d:                  s = 77
    if a == 1 and b <= 5 and c == 'xyz' and not d:              s = 17
    if a == 1 and 5 < b <= 8 and c in ('abc', 'def') and d:     s = 28
    if a == 1 and 5 < b <= 8 and c in ('abc', 'def') and not d: s = 39
    if a == 1 and 5 < b <= 8 and c == 'xyz' and d:              s = 10
    if a == 1 and 5 < b <= 8 and c == 'xyz' and not d:          s = 45
    if a == 1 and b > 8 and c in ('abc', 'def') and d:          s = 59
    if a == 1 and b > 8 and c in ('abc', 'def') and not d:      s = 48
    if a == 1 and b > 8 and c == 'xyz' and d:                   s = 29
    if a == 1 and b > 8 and c == 'xyz' and not d:               s = 24
    if a == 2 and b <= 5 and c in ('abc', 'def') and d:         s = 39
    if a == 2 and b <= 5 and c in ('abc', 'def') and not d:     s = 51
    if a == 2 and b <= 5 and c == 'xyz' and d:                  s = 69
    if a == 2 and b <= 5 and c == 'xyz' and not d:              s = 42
    if a == 2 and 5 < b <= 8 and c in ('abc', 'def') and d:     s = 23
    if a == 2 and 5 < b <= 8 and c in ('abc', 'def') and not d: s = 11
    if a == 2 and 5 < b <= 8 and c == 'xyz' and d:              s = 12
    if a == 2 and 5 < b <= 8 and c == 'xyz' and not d:          s = 89
    if a == 2 and b > 8 and c in ('abc', 'def') and d:          s = 54
    if a == 2 and b > 8 and c in ('abc', 'def') and not d:      s = 23
    if a == 2 and b > 8 and c == 'xyz' and d:                   s = 22
    if a == 2 and b > 8 and c == 'xyz' and not d:               s = 98
    if a == 3 and b <= 5 and c in ('abc', 'def') and d:         s = 91
    if a == 3 and b <= 5 and c in ('abc', 'def') and not d:     s = 15
    if a == 3 and b <= 5 and c == 'xyz' and d:                  s = 55
    if a == 3 and b <= 5 and c == 'xyz' and not d:              s = 36
    if a == 3 and 5 < b <= 8 and c in ('abc', 'def') and d:     s = 66
    if a == 3 and 5 < b <= 8 and c in ('abc', 'def') and not d: s = 82
    if a == 3 and 5 < b <= 8 and c == 'xyz' and d:              s = 20
    if a == 3 and 5 < b <= 8 and c == 'xyz' and not d:          s = 98
    if a == 3 and b > 8 and c in ('abc', 'def') and d:          s = 77
    if a == 3 and b > 8 and c in ('abc', 'def') and not d:      s = 23
    if a == 3 and b > 8 and c == 'xyz' and d:                   s = 41
    if a == 3 and b > 8 and c == 'xyz' and not d:               s = 84
    return s
```

## Solution

I found this solution which uses `itertools.product`. but we need to pay attention to the order of `listvalues`:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
def f(a, b, c, d):
    listconditions = [[a==1, a==2, a==3],
                      [b <= 5, 5 < b <= 8, b > 8],
                      [c in ("abc", "def"), c == 'xyz'],
                      [d, not d]]

        listvalues = [75, 83, 77, 17, 28, 39, 10, 45, 59, 48, 29, 24,
                      39, 51, 69, 42, 23, 11, 12, 89, 54, 23, 22, 98,
                      91, 15, 55, 36, 66, 82, 20, 98, 77, 23, 41, 84]

    allcombinations = itertools.product(*listconditions)

    test = [np.logical_and.reduce(i) for i in allcombinations]

    return sum(np.array(test) * listvalues)

f(1,7,'abc',False)
```

> 39

Comment: Could you please clarify if any of the answers fits your question, or they did not quite what you needed.

Comment: All answers fit my question. Thank you all

Comment: (ping) Could you please help stackoverflow mechanics by accepting the answer you liked the most (if there is one indeed) so that authors of answers don't see this question in their active list ;) thank you for participation. If none of answers was relevant pls ignore this ping.

Comment: @AndrewLyashko while it’s encouraged to accept answers, the OP is not required to

Answer (score 2):

You could use a dictionary to contain indices for `a` and values in `b`:

```py
options_a = {'GBP': 0, 'AUD': 0, 'CNY': 0, 'NZD': 0, 'EUR': 1, 'USD': 1, 'CHF': 1, 'CAD': 1, 'SGD': 1, 'HKD': 1, 'JPY': 1}

options_b = {'[00Y, 01Y]': ('90', '95'), '[01Y, 02Y]': ('85', '90'), '[02Y, 03Y]': ('80', '85'), '[03Y, 04Y]': ('75', '80'), '[04Y, 05Y]': ('70', '75'), '[05Y, 07Y]': (None, '60'), '[07Y, 10Y]': (None, '55')}

# Get the index of the tuple by looking up 'a' first
idx = options_a[a]

# Then use that index when you look up 'b' to grab the correct value for 'c'
c = options_b[b][idx]
```

If you get any combinations you didn't plan for, it will raise a `KeyError`,  which you may or may not want to handle:

```py
try:
    idx = options_a[a]
    tup = options_b[b]
except KeyError:
    print("Do something")
else:
    c = tup[idx]
```

Comment: Is there a similar way when conditions are comparison?

Comment: @PierreYvesCorre could you provide an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Use for loop and list to do what you want I assume that, you need to decrease the value by 5

```
tupel1 =  ('GBP', 'AUD', 'CNY', 'NZD')
tuple2 = ('EUR', 'USD', 'CHF', 'CAD', 'SGD', 'HKD', 'JPY')
listb = ['[00Y, 01Y]' ,'[02Y, 03Y]','[03Y, 04Y]','[04Y, 05Y]',]

for i in range(listb):
  if listb[i]==b:
    if a in tuble1:
       c = str(90 - 5*i)
    elif a in tuble2:
       c = str(95 -5*i)
```

Comment: do type casting

Comment: Small typo: `tuple1` and `tuple2` are defined initially, but `tuble` used in the code block.

Answer (score 0):

Another take, a one-liner:

```
(95 if a in {'EUR', 'USD', 'CHF', 'CAD', 'SGD', 'HKD', 'JPY'} else 90) - 5 * [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7].index(int(b[1:3]))
```

Or packing it more, but getting dirty:

```
(95 if a in 'EUR USD CHF CAD SGD HKD JPY' else 90) - 5 * [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7].index(int(b[1:3]))
```